# How do I create a Test Suite at runtime

Tags: java, testing, junit, test-suite

```
Class A {

    @Test     
    @CustomAnnotation(attrib1 = "foo"; attrib2 = "moo"; attrib3 = "poo") 
    void methodA(){ }

    @Test      
    @CustomAnnotation(attrib1 = "blahblah"; attrib2 = "flahflah"; attrib3 = "klahklah") 
    void methodB(){ }

    @Test      
    @CustomAnnotation(attrib1 = "foo"; attrib2 = "flahflah"; attrib3 = "poo") 
    void methodC(){ }
}
```

Now, using reflection, my annotation processing class will return me a SET/LIST of methods which match my criteria (say,attrib1="foo") - Method A and method C will satisfy. Now I need to add these to a test suite at runtime and run that.

How can I add them to the test suite?

Comment: Maybe there's a feature in JUnit, which does what you want: http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.html

Comment: Made it from experimental to stable: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Categories

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`.  You should be able to specify the set of tests to run (methods that have to be executed as tests) using `org.junit.runner.Request`: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html#run(org.junit.runner.Request)